# 'Could not find binary sh' when running `yarn install` after gitlab webhook

Tags: php, git, shell, npm

Some mysterious is happening on my server and I don't know why. I'm trying to run a simple deploy script containing `yarn install`. The script is triggered by a POST request from a Gitlab CE server. The specs of the server:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Nginx (mainline)
- Node 6 / Npm 3
- PHP 7.1

The webhook is received by a PHP file containing something like this:

```
exec('cd /var/www/example.com && sh deploy > deploy.log 2>&1 &');
```

The `deploy` file contains a few commands like `git pull`, `composer install` and `yarn install`. Everything is working fine, except for Yarn/NPM. It keeps complaining about this:

```
error /var/www/example.com/node_modules/node-sass: Couldn't find the binary sh
```

I've searched for hours (maybe days) to find a solution, but no success so far. Hope someone can help me (and someone else too).

Comment: Maybe someone wants to know: I'm now using Gitlab CI to build, test and deploy everything. Much easier! Everything is build (locally) in the Docker image now.

Answer (score -2):

```
error Couldn't find the binary cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpa
ck/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/larave
l-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
```

[image]

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful